# How do I get the files back from the .git directory alone?

Tags: git

Is it possible to get source code from GIT .pack files? I have the full .git folder but the source is entirely missing. Is it possible to use these pack files and get source code out of that from master branch? I just have access to .pack files. No repository URL!

Comment: If you have the full `.git` folder, then you should use the `git` command line tools to access the data within. Trying to pick apart the pack files manually, while possible, requires extremely detailed knowledge of `git` internals and lots of work.

Comment: How can I access the data within? Could you please give me some sample?

Comment: Perhaps you need to start with a basic tutorial on `git`. There are many out there, but [this](http://git-scm.com) is e reasonable starting place - look under "Documentation".

Comment: I have used Tortoise GIT. I just want to know how to get source code from the .git folder. Do I have to read everything as you suggested for this?

Comment: Probably not, but without anything more specific than "how can I access the data within", trying to guess exactly what you are trying to do is pointless.

Comment: @twalberg: I want to access the source files. It is a PHP project but all I am given is the .git folder not even GIT url using which I can clone the code. Does this help?

Comment: Rename `.git` to `foo.git`, then run `git clone foo.git foo`, `cd foo`, and then you can `git log`, `git branch`, `git checkout`, whatever....

Comment: That's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), Jack -- things are quite simpler, luckily.

Comment: @kostix: Cool. git clone helped me get things done. I magically got all source code!

Comment: Well, OK, @twalberg's solution is slightly less elegant than mine, but anyway we're not about elegance here, right? :-)

Comment: Yes, we are.(atleast I am) :)

Comment: ...and there's no need to rename the directory before cloning -- Git pays no attention to this; the `.git` suffix is just a convention for naming bare repositories.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. git core command printed nothing as I stated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.git` directory is a full repository, just missing its work tree *inside* which it's typically located.  So it just sits there unaware that there's no more enclosing work tree.

But to get things back is very simple:

```
$ mkdir project
$ mv /path/to/that/.git project
... Now ".git" is right under "project" ...
$ cd project
$ git branch
... see the list of branches here ...
$ git checkout -f master
```

The `-f` command-line option to `git checkout` is crucial if the HEAD reference currently points to the branch you want to check out—otherwise Git won't try to create the files in the work tree thinking that you *have* them checked out but consciously deleted.

Comment: Thanks kostix but I get error: "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree"

Comment: @Jack, Do you *really* have ".git" right under the directory you're running `git checkout` in? I mean, I of course tested my answer before posting so you might hit some configuration problem.

Comment: @Jack, please try running `git config core.worktree` -- does it print something? Also, are you sure you have no `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable currently set? (That is, `echo $GIT_WORK_TREE` should print nothing.)

Comment: Although I got the solution. Let me try your solution so I get better understanding

Comment: You can also just do `git clone /path/to/the/.git newprojectfolder` and it will clone the repository, creating a new local repository in `newprojectfolder`.